# Logging decorator not outputting DEBUG level messages

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have created a logged function which is to act as a parameterised logging decorator.

```
from functools import wraps
import logging

def logged(level, name=None, message=None):
    '''
    Add logging to a function.  
    - level is the logging level.
    - name is the logger
    - message is the log message
    If name and mesage are not provided, the module and function name are used by default.
    '''
    
    def decorate(func):
        logname = name if name else func.__module__
        log = logging.getLogger(logname)
        logmsg = message if message else func.__name__
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
               
        # create formatter
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        # add formatter to ch
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add ch to logger
        log.addHandler(ch)
        
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            log.log(level,logmsg)
            return(func(*args, **kwargs))
        
        return wrapper
    return decorate
```

When I call this with logging.CRITICAL, I get a log output to console.

```
@logged(logging.CRITICAL,'example')
def spam():
    print('SPAM....!')

spam()
```

This outputs:

```
2021-07-14 16:10:11,699 - example - CRITICAL - spam
```

But this returns no output to the console at all:

```
@logged(logging.DEBUG)
def add(x,y):
    return x + y

add(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `log.setLevel`. The default is `logging.WARNING`.

```py
>>> log.getEffectiveLevel()
30
>>> logging.WARNING
30
>>> log.isEnabledFor(logging.WARNING)
True
>>> log.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO)
False
>>> log.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)
False
>>>
```

Since you're not convinced, I saved your code as orig.py and added the .setLevel call to a copy then saved it as modified.py

Here's what's printed on my machine.

```
>py orig.py

>py modified.py
2021-07-14 17:11:04,202 - __main__ - DEBUG - add

>fc /n orig.py modified.py
Comparing files orig.py and MODIFIED.PY
***** orig.py
   15:          log = logging.getLogger(logname)
   16:          logmsg = message if message else func.__name__
***** MODIFIED.PY
   15:          log = logging.getLogger(logname)
   16:          log.setLevel(level)
   17:          logmsg = message if message else func.__name__
*****


>
```

And here's the full modified code

```py
from functools import wraps
import logging

def logged(level, name=None, message=None):
    '''
    Add logging to a function.  
    - level is the logging level.
    - name is the logger
    - message is the log message
    If name and mesage are not provided, the module and function name are used by default.
    '''
    
    def decorate(func):
        logname = name if name else func.__module__
        log = logging.getLogger(logname)
        log.setLevel(level)
        logmsg = message if message else func.__name__
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
               
        # create formatter
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        # add formatter to ch
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add ch to logger
        log.addHandler(ch)
        
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            log.log(level,logmsg)
            return(func(*args, **kwargs))
        
        return wrapper
    return decorate
    
@logged(logging.DEBUG)
def add(x,y):
    return x + y

add(1,2)
```

Comment: I am setting the level.  It is being passed as the decorator parameter, then used to set the level in the decorator function

Comment: No, you do not. You're just calling `log.log(level,logmsg)` which will have no effect if level is < logging.WARNING (the default). Just try calling `log.setLevel(level)` please.

Comment: So much for the Python Cookbook then